# Xcode 4.3.1 installed, "missing SDK" issue

Tags: xcode

I installed xcode 4.3.1 yesterday and everything seemed to work fine.  I was able to build, add projects to my device etc.

Then I restarted my machine...

Now whenever I try and build my project I am getting this error

> The run destination iPhone 5.1 Simulator is not valid for Running the scheme 'myproject' The scheme 'myproject' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iPhone 5.1 Simulator. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

So what happened here during my restart of the machine?  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the Build SDK in Project settings is set to Latest SDK.

[image]

Also, do a clean (CMD+K) and run again.

Comment: Under 'Build Settings' the Base SDK release is set to Latest iOS (iOS 5.1) and the Debug is set to iphonesimulator4.0

Comment: No other options?  Everything Ive read says setting this is the issue, but mine is set and its still not working.  On the left side Under my project name, it says missing base SDK....